# High temperature and high failure GU10 LEDs

Tags: led

I have nineteen GU10 LED lamps in the ceiling in my kitchen.  Besides a reasonably high failure rate I also find that they are untouchably hot when changing them.  Could there be an issue here?  Poor lamp quality? Should they really get that warm?  I'm thinking potential fire risk. They are turned on and off via my Loxone system which uses interposing relays to drive this lamp circuit.  The relay has also failed (held on contacts) which makes me worry even more.  There are maximum 10 lamps in each circuit.  The relays used in the Loxone are HF33F subminature intermediate power relays.   Any clues?

Comment: Where did you buy them from? Do they have a brochure or data sheet? Is there any product guarantee?

Comment: the post is a better fit at https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: are the lamps completely enclosed inside a fixture?

Comment: Are they running on AC power (120V, 60Hz or 230V, 50Hz)? What is their rated power (how many watts)? You should include more details, including pictures of your bulbs and your setup.

Comment: Buy higher efficiency bulbs and they won't get so hot and burn out.

Comment: Overdriven. Add a resistor in series to lower the current. Most of the time when overdriven you don't notice the differents in light when adding a resistor but in produced heat. If you have a resistor box, you can experiment which value of resistance give the best/plausible result.

Answer (score 3):

LED bulbs/lights generally fail for two reasons:

1. Too much power or current is run through LEDs;
2. Too much heat generated without sufficient surface to dissipate it.

### Reason 1

Most manufacturers use fewer LEDs than what should be used in their lamps, or they run their LEDs at a higher current than what they were rated for, both for saving the space in the LED lights/bulbs and for cutting costs (higher profits). 
For example, when making a 3W bulb, they would need **at least** 10 LED "chips" (individual LEDs) rated for 0.3W each. Using even more LEDs would make each LED a bit more efficient and significantly longer lasting, but it would make a more expensive light. 
So, in order to have competitive prices, they use the least amount of components that would under most circumstances survive the warranty period.

### Reason 2

The standard bulb bodies were made for the old incandescent types which were not affected by high temperatures at which they typically operated. 
LED bulbs were meant to be quick and convenient replacements, but the standard bulb models are too small to sufficiently radiate the heat away and keep the LEDs cool which is necessary for their long life. 
Realistically, E27 models over 4-5W will be too hot, GU10 even worse because they are smaller (2-3W at most). 
This is the fact that almost no manufacturer will tell you: if you want LED lights to last longer, you need significantly larger surface area than what the old bulb bodies can provide in most cases.

### SOLUTION:

If you have someone who knows electronics, they could do what I would do (both of the things below):

1. Modify purchased LED bulbs or lights to use no more than half of their rated power - 1/3 or 1/4 would be even better;
2. Use more of the modified bulbs/lights to provide sufficient lighting while not overheating the lights.

Even better, buy a single large panel LED light (any brand or model) that is rated for 3 times more power than what you need, then modify it to use 1/3 of the power which will greatly reduce both the heating of and the stress on the individual LEDs, as well as on the power supply. 
Those panels typically have a separate "LED driver" (power supply) inside them, you can open it and triple the value of the resistor(s) which determine the output current/power.

That is one sure way to make your LED light last longer. 
The kitchen ceiling is usually warmer or hotter than the rest of the house, which exacerbates the LEDs' own heating and makes them fail much sooner than expected. 
Once you cut their self-heating down greatly, the added heat from the kitchen will not be as detrimental to their life expectancy as it is now when they're running at or above their limits already.

Comment: In Dubai, by law, LED bulbs have to reach a much higher standard, This topic is discussed here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klaJqofCsu4&ab_channel=bigclivedotcom. Also note that in this YouTube channel there are many practical demonstrations of how to modify bulbs to last a lot longer and use less power, as suggested in the answer.